# flutter fvm issues when installing on mac android studio

Tags: android, flutter, dart, fvm

Recently there are two projects that i am working and they are different versions i did the setup 2.0.6 to the project and set the path as well, but its still giving me error for the project

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 2.0.5.                               
                                                                        
Because project name depends on flutter_invitereferrals from path which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.0.6, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter project name...                           
pub get failed (1; Because flutter project name depends on flutter_invitereferrals from path which requires Flutter SDK version >=2.0.6, version solving failed.)
The pubspec.lock file has changed since the .dart_tool/package_config.json file was generated, please run "pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

[image: Configurations image for project]

Comment: invalidate caches , fvm flutter clean and try again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, running `fvm flutter clean` fixed the issue in my case